# A simple regex solution for digit grouping and validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, number-formatting

I had a requirement to group digits (adding thousands separators) on both sides of the decimal point (the whole and the fractional parts) using javascript. I investigated whether this would be possible without too much complexity using regex.

The solutions available online seem to be focused on grouping whole numbers or only to the left of the decimal point, so I tried to come up with my own solution, including a validation regex...

Comment: What did you come up with and can you give us examples of input and their expected outputs?

Comment: @ctwheels I didn't include the example inputs and outputs in the question as I was already posting a sample in an answer, but if it's alright to edit the question, I can show some examples in the question as well... I thought the answer would be explanation enough. (This was meant to be a question - answer pair)

Comment: Gotcha, are the results supposed to be mirrored separators after the decimal point?

Comment: @ctwheels I'm not exactly sure what is meant by mirrored separators, but the separators are to be the same on both sides of the decimal point, and the positions of the separators should be mirrored in the sense that you should start counting from the decimal point outwards, placing separators every three digits...

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. It provides a much simpler regex and method than your existing code. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the snippet only tests using the given validation regex, so if it is not sound, the test results would be invalid...

```js
function addThousandsSeparators(n) {
  return n.toString().replace(/-?\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))/gy, '$&,').replace(/\d{3}(?=\d)/g, '$&,')
}

function validateThousandsSeparators(n) {
  return /^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.(?:\d{3},)*\d{1,3})?$/.test(n)
}

var tests = [
  0,
  1,
  1.1,
  1.0123456789,
  -10.012345678,
  210.01234567,
  -3210.0123456,
  43210.012345,
  -543210.01234,
  6543210.0123,
  -76543210.012,
  876543210.01,
  -9876543210.1,
  1,
  10,
  -210,
  -3210,
  43210,
  543210,
  -6543210,
  -76543210,
  876543210,
  9876543210,
  0.0123456789,
  .012345678,
  -0.01234567,
  -.0123456,
  0.012345,
  .01234,
  -0.0123,
  -.012,
  0.01,
  .1
]
, i

function test(n) {
  n = addThousandsSeparators(n)
  console.log(
    (
      validateThousandsSeparators(n) ?
        'valid:   ' : 'invalid: '
    ) + n
  )
}

for(i of tests)
  test(i)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `console.log` instead of a convoluted custom log?

Comment: @ThejakaMaldeniya there's checkbox on the left side of snippets `Show console`

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

Please note that the output is what the OP expects. The output's decimal points should mirror the whole number separators such that `1234.1234` becomes `1,234.123,4` and **not** `1,234.1,234`. For this opposite effect (format of `1,234.1,234`), please expand and run the snippet directly below.

```js
var nums = [ 0, 1, 1.1, 1.0123456789, -10.012345678, 210.01234567, -3210.0123456, 43210.012345, -543210.01234, 6543210.0123, -76543210.012, 876543210.01, -9876543210.1, 1, 10, -210, -3210, 43210, 543210, -6543210, -76543210, 876543210, 9876543210, 0.0123456789, .012345678, -0.01234567, -.0123456, 0.012345, .01234, -0.0123, -.012, 0.01, .1 ];

nums.forEach(function(n){
  console.log(addSeparators(n));
});

function addSeparators(n) {
  var regex = /\d{3}(?![-.]|$)/g;
  var replace = `$&,`;
  n = n.toString();
  n = reverseNumber(n).replace(regex, replace);
  return reverseNumber(n);
}

function reverseNumber(n) {
  return n.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

---

### Code

The code below provides a simple regex and method to adding separators. The string is first reversed to add separators to the whole number part, then reversed once again to add separators to the decimal number part.

```js
var nums = [ 0, 1, 1.1, 1.0123456789, -10.012345678, 210.01234567, -3210.0123456, 43210.012345, -543210.01234, 6543210.0123, -76543210.012, 876543210.01, -9876543210.1, 1, 10, -210, -3210, 43210, 543210, -6543210, -76543210, 876543210, 9876543210, 0.0123456789, .012345678, -0.01234567, -.0123456, 0.012345, .01234, -0.0123, -.012, 0.01, .1 ];

nums.forEach(function(n){
  console.log(addSeparators(n));
});

function addSeparators(n) {
  var regex = /\d{3}(?=[^.,]+$)(?!-)/g;
  var replace = `$&,`;
  n = n.toString();
  n = reverseNumber(n).replace(regex, replace);
  n = reverseNumber(n).replace(regex, replace);
  return n;
}

function reverseNumber(n) {
  return n.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `\d{3}` Match a digit exactly 3 times
- `(?=[^.,]+$)` Ensure no decimal points or separators exist between here and the end of the line (prevents duplicate separators and ensures it's only manipulating the part of the string after the `.`)
- `(?!-)` Ensure what follows is not the negative sign (this prevents, for example, `-543210.01234` from becoming `-,543,210.012,34`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ctwheels. I've taken a look at your solution, and it occured to me that the regex could also be written as /\d{3}(?=[^.,-]+-?$)/g or /\d{3}(?=\d+-?$)/g eliminating the negative lookahead. Incidentally, did you decide to reverse instead of splitting at the point so you could reuse the same regex? I was not sure if splitting, reversing twice and rejoining would have a performance impact, but this is not especially a concern if the function isn't used to process large data-sets, and the solution is simple enough, and the explanation will be useful for the readers...